# boost::system::system_error not nothrow copy constructible?

Tags: c++, boost

shouldn't this be true?

```
std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<boost::system::system_error>::value
```

How can I throw a boost::system::system_error without getting the nothrow copy constructible warning? e.g.

```
boost::system::error_code ec;
throw boost::system::system_error(ec);
```

Comment: what warning do you get?

Comment: It's from ReSharper C++. It says the system_error exception copy constructor might throw an exception.

Comment: I am constructing it when throwing it. Doesn't matter if I change the syntax. Problem here is that std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<boost::system::system_error>::value is false, while e.g. std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<std::runtime_error>::value is true. They should both be true right?

Comment: I changed my CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD from 14 to 17 and the warning goes away...